# Schauder Basis and Approximation property

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I have just read that every Banach space with a countable schauder basis will have the approximation property and so every compact operator will be the limit of some $T_n's$ finite rank operators. Now is there a relatively "normal" example  of a Normed vector space with a schauder basis that doesn't have the approximation property?

And also can we have a space with the approximation property but that doesn't have a schauder basis ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that every Banach space with a *countable* schauder basis has this approximation property. If that's the case, you're looking for non-separable Banach spaces.

Comment: By definition, a Schauder basis is countable. There are notions of uncountable bases, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89340/uniqueness-of-dimension-in-banach-spaces, but they're called by a different name. A famous example by Per Enflo shows that there are separable Banach spaces without a Schauder basis and do not have the approximation property, see https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889774.

Comment: @Chrystomath Whoops, thanks for the correction

Comment: [This](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/117/6402-11511_2006_Article_BF02392555.pdf) may be of interest.